# Access daughter DIV from other daughter without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a structure as below:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Tiger128 (v2)</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
         <input class="form-control" id="tiger128v2" placeholder="String to Hash" type="text">
     </div>
     <div class="panel-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-primary generate-hash" data-hash="tiger128v2">Generate Hash</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

When a user presses the `<a>` it runs a jQuery function (using `$('.generate-hash')` selector) which makes a `$.getJSON` request passing `data-hashtype`. When it returns the JSON object I need it to append some text to `<div class="panel-body">` however as you can see none of them have ID's.

What I have tried is something along the lines of:

```
$(this).parent().prev('.panel-body').append('Appending some text');
$(this).parent().parent().siblings(".panel-body").append('test');
```

But I cannot get it to work. Any suggestions?

---

```
$('.generate-hash').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var hashtype = $(this).data('hash');
                var string = $(this).closest('.panel').find('input').val();
                console.log('Started hash request for ' + hashtype + ' with a value of ' + string);
                $.getJSON('ajax/hash.php', {
                    hashtype: hashtype,
                    string: string
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log('success function');
                    if(data.type == 'success'){
                        // Here is where i need to select the parents
                        $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".panel-body").append('test');
                        $(this).parent().prev('.body').append('<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Generated Hash:</strong> <code>' + data.hash + '</code></div>');
                        console.log('success msg found');
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().prev('.body').append('<div class="alert alert-' + data.type + '">' + data.msg + '</div>');
                        console.log('error msg found');
                    }
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    $(this).parent().prev('.body').append('<div class="alert alert-error"><strong>Error:</strong> We could not generate the hash for some reason. The details are below:</div>');
                    console.log('unable to find hash.php or other error');
                });
            });
```

Comment: Why don't you append an ID to your div with jquery and then work from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.prev()` method:

```
$(this).parent().prev('.body').append('Something');
```

Or `.closest()` method:

```
$(this).closest('.box').find('.body').append('Something');
```

Edit:

You should cache the `this` object, within the context of the Deferred object's handlers `this` doesn't refer to the clicked element, also replace `.success()` with `.done()`:

```
$('.generate-hash').click(function (e) {
    // ...
    var $this = $(this);
    $.getJSON('ajax/hash.php', {
        hashtype: hashtype,
        string: string
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('success function');
        if(data.type == 'success'){
            // Here is where i need to select the parents
            $this.parent().parent().siblings(".panel-body").append('test');
            // ...
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $this.parent()...
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, your suggestion was not working for me so I have updated my answer to include the exact code. Could you have another look please?

Answer (score 2):

use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

closest() selects the first element that matches the selector, up from the DOM tree while [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects all the elements that are parent of another element in the DOM tree.

```
$(this).closest('.box').find('.body').append('Something');
```

reference **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Comment: `.closest()` selects the closest matching parent element not the sibling of the parent element.

Comment: But it still returns an empty collection.

Comment: ohh yes first we select box then we will find body @undefined :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, try prev()

```
 $(this).parent().prev().append('Something');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe pure javascript might work

```
var box = this.parentNode.parentNode,
    body = box.getElementsByClassName('body')[0];

body.innerHTML += 'Something';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(this).parents('.box').find('.body').append('Something');
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.box').find('.body').append('Something');
```

Read [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents) and [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest)